# Edit Images From the Front End without Access to WP Admin

Tags: plugin-development, front-end

Building a members plugin that users will **not have access to WP Admin** interface has been a challenge. Now what I want is  to give to our users, the option to upload images, view them and ultimate be able to edit them. Where the edit part is the (**resize/Scale/crop**) option that wordpress has in core but in the WP Admin.

So what are my options to achieve that ( Front end Edit images)?